# how to spell git revision range with single endpoint

Tags: git, range, revision, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I was lookin for range based on single commit to be able to do a `cherry-pick`

In manual for `gitrevisions` I'm reading

```
<rev>^-<n>, e.g. HEAD^-, HEAD^-2
           Equivalent to <rev>^<n>..<rev>, with <n> = 1 if not given.
```

But I cant use it. Any help?

**UPDATE**:

I want to be able to do something like

```
git cherry-pick <rev><some static tricks>
```

to cherry pick giver  and its - say - three parents.

Comment: What range *do* you want?

Answer (score 0):

what I am getting from your question is that you want to cherry-pick multiple commits.

for cherry-pick multiple commits use

```
git cherry-pick commithashA^..commithashB
```

Here **commithashA**: is the starting commit hash and **commithashB**: is the last commit you want to cherry-pick.

Let us know if it resolved your problem.
Or your problem is something else.

Thanks!

Comment: thx @rahul, I know that option. I want to use just single `commithash`